# While using $cordovaOauth getting a ‘could not find InAppBrowser

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, facebook-login, ngcordova

I am trying to integrate facebook login using $cordovaOauth plugin. But it always resulting an error message 'Could not find InAppBrowser'.

I already added the inapp browser plugin through https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git3 and also tried to add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser in config file. But the same error shows while test it on Android/Ios devices.

I had it all working 1 month ago and now I'm unsure what's happened.
Any assistance or ideas would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, this started happening to me also. I thought it had something to do with me using a different plugin for managing facebook authentication. (`cordova-plugin-facebook4`) But that wasn't the case. I don't know why this is happening. I do use `cordovaOauth` for twitter and instagram, so I need the inappbrowser to work.

If you know you have `InAppBrowser` installed, just go in `ng-cordova.js` where `isInAppBrowserInstalled` is defined and `return true;`

It's not a fix, but it worked for me.